# Is there pause available in mediarecorder class

Tags: android, mediarecorder

Is there a way to pause the recording and start after a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **no**

Once you are recording the only possible actions are stop and reset.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pause() functionality when recording media.  I would try conjoining two separate audio files together once the user hits your "stop" button in the app.  Either that, or try to find a way to write to the same file stream after using the stop() method.

Comment: Could u please post that code, or the link to concatenate two separate audio files.