# pause option while recording voice android

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediarecorder

This is how i'm recording audio :-

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

and to start recording :-

```
    recorder.start(); // Recording is now started
```

and to stop :

```
    recorder.stop(); // Recording is now stopped
```

But how to pause while recording, also searched in stackoverflow and developer site and i found that there is no api to pause the recording. But there are many apps in google play where pause option is available, so that means some work around has to be done.

One way can be using the same audio file and appending data to it.

But, can anyone help me with some code.... Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like someone has had similar problem (possible duplicate):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256826/android-pause-voice-recorder-and-resume

Comment: ya, but no solutions ... :(

Comment: There is a solution of stopping, preparing and starting again, isn't it?

Comment: sorry, but i cant find anything inside pause function :p

Comment: What about reading first(accepted and the only) answer?

Comment: You could use the `AudioRecord` class instead. Then you could keep reading data while you're in a paused state and just throw the data away. But you'd have to do the compression yourself if you want compressed outout.

Comment: It seems there are no option for pausing.See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007682/how-to-pause-resume-a-recording-created-with-mediarecorder, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256826/android-pause-voice-recorder-and-resume

Answer (score 0):

**Once you are recording the only possible actions are stop and reset.**

Android MediaRecorder class not provide pause functionality so, we can't pause Recording but stop recording is available.