# Best Way to combine Audio files in Android

Tags: android, media

I am developing Recording App that includes **Pause/Play** option.

I tried with both **Media Recorder** and **AudioRecord**

In case of **AudioRecord** , the recorded audio consumes larger size, so if the recording size increases say for eg: if i record 1 min audio it **consumes 40 to 50MB** an it really paining to combine by converting it to .**raw file** and **send to php server**.

So i tried with **Media Recorder**, it **consumes less size**,but not able to combine using the previous way handled in Audio Record.

Next step i tried with **Android NDK**- really paining for even Set up process.

Now my question is that which is the best way to combine recorded audio files

1. Using Android NDk
2. Reading the byte data from Audio and combining -If i use this there is problem with Headers of Recording format say amr,wav like that.

Also if i try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653861/join-two-wav-files-from-java/653873#653873) , i am not able to get javax.sound package , So i tried with Plugins but no luck..

Please Suggest best way to do this. Also i tried with all this following links

[Audio Link 1](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/AudioRecorder.2/src/com/varma/samples/audiorecorder/RecorderActivity.java)

[Audio Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179709/audio-appending-using-randomaccessfile)

[Audio Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128440/is-there-pause-available-in-mediarecorder-class)

[Audio Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161231/merging-pcm-audio-files)

Provide me Good tutorial or samples or links.Thanks.

Comment: For small audio files I would just use SoundPool but for large files that need paused and resumed have you looked at MediaPlayer?

Comment: Check my question correctly, i am asking for Audio recording and not for Media Player

Comment: Hi,please me to develp native C++ code using the NDK for audio combine. i am using media recording and MPEG-4 file format. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this your best bet would be to develop native C++ code using the NDK.

Comment: Hi,please me to develp native C++ code using the NDK for audio combine. i am using media recording and MPEG-4 file format. please help me.

Comment: i have tried convert second MP4 audio files to byte array and append it in to first mp4 audio file ,i get a combined audio file but the combined file does not play second audio but file size is increased.

Comment: You can use [mp4parser](http://mp4parser.googlecode.com) to combine MP4 files of the same type without using native libs. AppendExample will do.